# Off-topic : network discussions

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic, networking

The following question : https://superuser.com/questions/257073/good-book-for-networks has been closed as off-topic.

The question I'm asking: if network discussion are not meant to be on super-user, where does it belong? Would serverfault appropriate for that question (I'm not sure about this cause SF is more for professionals?)

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Can has read [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Home networking questions are certainly on topic for Super User.

Asking for book recommendations, like shopping, is not.

Comment: Hum ok. I did not see it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more insight, check http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/